# Why does this piped command fail?

Tags: cmd, windows-7

With a file %v%.txt present, this batch file:

```
PROMPT $g
SET v="d"
FOR %%F IN ("*.txt") DO ( TYPE "%%F"  )
FOR %%F IN ("*.txt") DO ( SORT "%%F"  )
FOR %%F IN ("*.txt") DO ( TYPE "%%F" | SORT )
```

produces

```
>PROMPT $g

>SET v="d"

>FOR %F IN ("*.txt") DO (TYPE "%F"   )

>(TYPE "%v%.txt"   )
content
>FOR %F IN ("*.txt") DO (SORT "%F"   )

>(SORT "%v%.txt"   )
content

>FOR %F IN ("*.txt") DO (TYPE "%F"   | SORT  )

>(TYPE "%v%.txt"   | SORT  )
The system cannot find the file specified.

>
```

Why "The system cannot find the file specified" from only the line having the piped command?

Answer (score 1):

using `echo` instead of `type` shows that expansion is done in the last command looking for `d.txt` instead of `%v%.txt`, it seems that line with `|` is parsed twice.

another example :

```
set a=^%b^%

set b=10

echo %a%

echo %a% | sort
```

Comment: Completely right. The command is first parsed in the `cmd` instance running the batch file (`%%F -> %v%.txt`). Each side of the pipe is handled by a new separate `cmd` instance that parses (`%v%.txt -> "d".txt`) and executes the command.

Comment: @MC ND, Wow, that's dumb. How was that ever expected to work, I wonder??
Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisJJ, pipes connect the sdtout from the *process* in the left side to the stdin of the *process* on the right side. While not the only solution, It has been implemented that way since early unix versions and it is the way shells like bash implement it today. It works, but it has some quirks that sometimes bite you.